# C# List<string> add index to list console output

Tags: c#, list

In the bellow sample scenario i like to add the index of the item to the output console. And i just dont get it to work.

```
        public static void Main()
        {
            List<string> myList = new List<string> { "This", "is", "a", "test" };
            foreach (var item in myList)
                Debug.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

Something like this

```
Debug.WriteLine(item.index + " : : + item);
```

Comment: Does it have to be foreach? You would probably be better off using a for loop and using the indexer.

Comment: Yes, you're so right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1) to get an items with their index and print it out

```cs
List<string> myList = new List<string> { "This", "is", "a", "test" };
foreach (var item in myList.Select((value, index) => new { value, index }))
    Debug.WriteLine($"{item.value}:{item.index}");
```

You can also use [`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_IndexOf__0_) method, bit it'll return a first index and can cause a problem, if list has a duplicated items

```cs
foreach (var item in myList)
    Debug.WriteLine($"{item}:{myList.IndexOf(item)}");
```

Using a regular `for` loop also might be an option

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++) 
    Debug.WriteLine($"{myList[i]}:{i}");
```

Comment: @RobertoPagnotta Welcome, you can approve an answer, if it solves your question:)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void Main()
{
    int index = 0;
    List<string> myList = new List<string> { "This", "is", "a", "test" };
    foreach (var item in myList)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(item + " " + index);
        index++;
    }
}
```

Remember that sometimes the simplest approach is the best, especially if you are a beginner. While Pavel's answer is also correct and preferable, if you need to ask this question you are just starting with programming, I would advice you to stick to general solutions (incrementing an index variable) which work in all programing languages. Once you are comfortable with those, move to language specific sugars

Answer (score 0):

You can declare `index` variable:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string> { "This", "is", "a", "test" };
var index = 0;
foreach (var item in myList)
    Console.WriteLine($"{item} {index++}");
```

Or using simple `for` loop where `i` is alread declared and your loop more flexible - you can iterate from end to start and from start to end of `List<T>`:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string> { "This", "is", "a", "test" };
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine($"{myList[i]} {i}");
}
```

Comment: Thanks also for your input, it also helps to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The C# foreach does not have an inbuilt index. You can go with two approaches.

```
int index=-1;
foreach (var item in myList){
     index++;
     Debug.WriteLine(index + ":" + item);
}
```

or you can use the forloop

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Length; i++)
{
   var item = myList[i];
   Debug.WriteLine(i+ ":" + item);
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a variable called 'index' when you could just use 'i' in your 'for loop'?

Comment: Was making it easier for him to understand

Comment: I understand the solutions mention above, I was just looking for a inbuilt index. Now I know why after hours of search I did not found anything relevant. In this case the best way is to create the index ID when I'm generating the `myList`. So I can simple loop thru `item.indexID`. If I generate the list indexes by using a for loop on a filtered list, I can't access the `myList` by using that index.

Comment: Yeah, you could do that. That would be a good approach if you want customized indexes but this works fine if you just want an index with an incremental value

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```cs
myList.IndexOf(item)
```

to access item's index so your code should be:

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    List<string> myList = new List<string> { "This", "is", "a", "test" };
    foreach (var item in myList)
        Debug.WriteLine(item + ": " + myList.IndexOf(item));
}
```

Comment: It's performance killer, see Pavel Anikhouski answer how to do this

Comment: For my specific case, as the list holds just 200 entries, this will do it. thanks for the input

Comment: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netcore-3.1) says that it will return the index of the first occurence of the item, so if you have the same string twice (for example a word "and") it will return the first index multiple times, so it is very bad solution in this case